# Determining correlation function of a process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Random process {$X_t,t\in T$} is weak stationary process and has a
> canonical representation $X_t=U_1\cos\lambda t+U_2\sin\lambda,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $U_k,k=1,2$ have a normal
> distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Determine the correlation function of a process.

I know that dispersion of $X_t$ and dispersion of $X_s$ is $\sigma^2$, but I don't know how to calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(X_s,X_t)$.

Can you help me?